# Куда делась вторая "м"?

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Почему "грамматика" пишется с двумя "м", а "грамота", "грамотный", грамотей" с одной "м"? Как известно, все эти слова произошли от греческого "gramma"(буква).

Comment: Многие ученики, забывая, что это разные слова, пишут "грамотическое задание"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы еще забыли спросить, почему грамота через О. 
На самом деле грамота и грамматика скорее всего произошли от разных греческих слов - и самое главное: заимствованы из разных исторических эпох.

"Грамота", заимствованное в византийский (среднегреческий) период слово γράμματα (надпись), а грамматика - просто древнегреческое γραμματική, которым в своих целях воспользовались лингвисты в относительно недавнее время (думаю, не ранее XVII века). 
При этом "грамота" было взято "на слух" при непосредственных контактах и уподоблено под русскую фонетику (кстати, удвоенные согласные уже тогда перестали произноситься и в греческом), а "грамматика" - только в письменном виде с соблюдением всех орфографических условностей, древнеграческий к тому времени давно был мертвым, письменным языком.